# Get dependent assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

Is there a way to get all assemblies that depend on a given assembly?

Pseudo:

```
Assembly a = GetAssembly();
var dependants = a.GetDependants();
```

Comment: Do you need it programatically? If not you can use MS Depends for that.

Comment: Programmatically. I need to use [AddProviderTransparent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783170.aspx) on all dependant types.

Comment: How would you define the scope? Assembly can know what it depends on but can it tell what depends on it? +1 for question ;)

Comment: @juergend Depends.exe does not show .NET / managed dependencies.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you wish to find the dependent assemblies from the current application domain, you could use something like the `GetDependentAssemblies` function defined below:

```
private IEnumerable<Assembly> GetDependentAssemblies(Assembly analyzedAssembly)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => GetNamesOfAssembliesReferencedBy(a)
                            .Contains(analyzedAssembly.FullName));
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetNamesOfAssembliesReferencedBy(Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(assemblyName => assemblyName.FullName);
}
```

The `analyzedAssembly` parameter represents the assembly for which you want to find all the dependents.

Comment: Everyone including me is a fool for nothing think of it. Straight and simple.

Comment: +1 Nice. I'd never seen Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() before. Looks like it was added in .Net 4. Well - you learn something every day.

Answer (score 7):

Programatically, you can use [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to do this.

Something like this (note this won't work if the debugger is attached - e.g. if you run it from inside VS itself):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDependentAssembly(string assemblyFilePath)
{
   //On my box, once I'd installed Mono, Mono.Cecil could be found at: 
   //C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.8\lib\mono\gac\Mono.Cecil\0.9.4.0__0738eb9f132ed756\Mono.Cecil.dll
   var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyFilePath);
   return assembly.MainModule.AssemblyReferences.Select(reference => reference.FullName);
}
```

If you don't need to do this programatically, then [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) or [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) can give you this information.

Comment: Your code returns a list of assemblies which are referenced by an assembly pointed by `assemblyFilePath`, doesn't it? Is this what OP is asking about? I think (maybe mistakenly) that the OP wants the opposite: given an assembly `A` find all assemblies that reference it. Am I missing something?

Comment: ahh - maybe you are right - not sure now. It depends if you read the title (which suggests what I have answered here), or the text description (which suggests you are right)!

Comment: Agreed, it's a bit confusing. But if I'm right, then the OP probably has to answer the question raised by StaWho in comments first! I see no other way to solve the problem than to search for each and every assembly in the "scope" and execute your code for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

First define your scope, e.g.:

1. All assemblies in my application's bin directory
2. All assemblies in my application's bin directory + all assemblies in the GAC
3. All assemblies on any machine in the world.

Then simply (*) iterate through all assemblies in your scope, and use reflection to check if they depend on your target assembly.

If you want indirect as well as direct references, you'll have to rinse and repeat for all the assemblies you find.

(*) Might not be quite so simple if your scope is 3 above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in possibility to get dependencies at runtime. 
So I think the easiest solution is define an extension method and use code from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Assemblydependencies.aspx) application. I used an application itself a years ago. But *do not* use code of it.

Hope this helps.