# Get all types that been use in specific assembly by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I need to get all the types that a specific assembly depend on.

For example if I have project A that have reference to project B. I want to get all the class's that been used in A and define in A or B including enums, interfaces, attributes, base class of a class, entities type that been use inside of methods at project A etc.

Is there some way to get all entities type?

Comment: Maybe can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849289/get-dependent-assemblies

Comment: This will give me only the assembly dependency. I need all types dependencies and not all the assembly declaration. For example only class A and class B and interface C in assembly X1.

Comment: With Reflection - as far as I know - there is no way to get whether a particular type has been used inside a method. This kind of stuff is not exposed. You can however get all the types that are used in parameters and as method returns, also get any types that are inherited by other types.